# jQuery .each() and jQuery .post()

Tags: jquery, ajax, arrays, each, .post

I've been trying for about a day now to get this method to work.

I'm trying to use the jQuery `.each()` function to perform an action for each element in a given array.

The array comes from a `.post()` request

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$.post("assets/scripts/chat/load_convos.php",{}, function(data) {

//perform the .each() function

});

})
```

The array is returned in this format `[56,98.24,46]` through the php file `load_convos.php`

This is the PHP file

```
$get_convos = mysql_query("SELECT status, partner_user_id FROM chat_convos WHERE user_id = '$user_id'");
$following_user_id = '';
$uids = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($get_convos)){
    array_push($uids, $row['partner_user_id']);
}
$following_user_id = implode(',', $uids);
echo "[$following_user_id]";
```

I honestly don't see what I'm doing wrong...

========EDIT==========

This is what I have done so far

```
$.each(data, function(value) { 
  alert(value); 
});
```

Comment: Sure, check out the edit I have made on the original post.

Comment: I don't have a head in php codes, so you have wrong code in php part too. Anyway, you must use function(index,value) instead of function(value).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

change the two last rows of your php script to

```
 echo json_encode($uids);
```

and in the jQuery - instead of trying to use `$.each`, use a regular for loop over the data that you received (you may also want to add a fourth parameter to the `$.post` to ensure that it handles the response as JSON)

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $.post("assets/scripts/chat/load_convos.php",{}, function(data) {
       for(var i in data){
         //console.log(i+":"+data[i]);
         alert(data[i]);
       }
    },"json");
 })
```

Comment: How do I now `alert(data)` each number in the array?

Comment: replace the `console.log(i+":"+data[i])` with `alert(data[i]);`
look at my edited code

Answer (score 2):

You do not have to make changes in your PHP code as per Yaron's suggestion. You can change your jquery code a little bit:

```
$.each(data, function(index, value) {
   alert(value);
});
```

See it in action here. http://jsfiddle.net/2KZvt/1/